# Find all non-negative integer polynomials that satisfy : $P(1) = 8 $ ; $P(2) =2012 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Find all non-negative integer polynomials that satisfy : $P(1) = 8 $ ;   $P(2) =2012 $

First, I set $Q(x) = P(x)+ax+b $ such that $1$ and $2$ are solutions of $ Q(x)$

$\Rightarrow 8+a+b = 0$  and  $2012 + 2a+b = 0$

$\Rightarrow a=-2004 ; b =1996 $

$\Rightarrow P(x) = (x-1)(x-2)R(x) +2004x-1996$

(Predicted result :$ P(x) = x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+x^4+x^3+x^2 $)

But we have one more condition that the coefficients of $P(x)$ are non-negative integers, so I think I need to add another condition for $R(x)$ . But I don't have any more ideas. I hope to get help from everyone. Thanks very much !

Comment: Your polynomial should be of the form $P(x) =(x-1)(x-2)R(x) +2004x-1996$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh sorry !

Comment: *Hint*: Since $P(2)=2012<2^{11}$, you know $\operatorname{deg}P\leq 10$ and you can bound individual coefficients.

Comment: Now use $R(x) =a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\dots +a_n$ and ensure that coefficients of $P(x) $ are non-negative. Thus for example we must have $2a_n\geq 1996$

Comment: @user10354138    Of course, thanks to that, I can only predict the outcome!

Comment: @user10354138   Can you say clearer ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\deg P \le 10$ since $2^{11} > 2012$ and $\deg P \ge 9$ since the sum of coefficients is $8$ and $7\times 256+128 < 2012$ while $8\times 256 \ne 2012$

Let now $P=a_nx^n+...+a_0, a_0,..a_n \ge 0$ integers and assume there is a coefficient $a_k \ge 2$ and take minimal $k$ such; decomposing binary $a_k=2^{b_1}+..+2^{b_r}, b_1>b_2>..>b_r \ge 0, b_1 \ge 1$ and replacing $P$ by the polynomial $P_1$ with coefficients $c_m=a_m+1$ if $k+b_j=m$ for some $b_j>0$ above in the decomposition of $a_k$, $c_k=0$ if $b_r \ne 0$, $c_k=1, b_r=0$ and $c_m=a_m$ for the rest (allowing $c_m=1$ if somehow $k+b_j>n$ for some $j$ so taking the corresponding $a_m=0$), we get a polynomial $P_1$ with non-negative coefficients, $c_m \le 1, m \le k$ and $P_1(2)=2012, P_1(1) < 8$ since $b_1 \ge 1$ means that we replace at least $2^{b_1} \ge 2$ with $1$ in the coefficients of $P_1$ so we decrease strictly their sum.

If $P_1$ has a coefficient at least $2$ it must be at some $k_1 >k$ now and we repeat the above getting $P_2$ etc

Eventually (as all such polynomials have degree at most $10$ we must stop), we get a polynomial $Q$ with all coefficients $0,1$ st $Q(2)=2012, Q(1) \le 8$ where we have $Q(1)=8$ precisely when there is no reduction and $Q=P$

But now $2^9+...1 < 2012$ so $\deg Q =10$ and then $2^8+..1 < 2^9<2012-2^{10}$ so $\deg(Q-x^{10})=9$ and similarly we see that since
$2012-(1024+512)>256, 2012-(1024+512+256)>128$ and also $2012-(1024+512+256+128)>64$ we cannot skip the powers until $6$ either, so $Q(x)=x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+R(x)$ with $R$ degree at most $5$ and coefficients $0,1$, while $R(1) \le 3, R(2)=28$

But then $\deg R \le 4$ and again since $28-16 >8$ we must have $\deg R=4, R=x^4+S, S(2)=12$ and $S$ has degree at most $3$, coefficients $0,1$ and at most two non zero such since $S(1) \le 2$. Plainly we must have $S=x^3+x^2$ and $Q=x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+x^4+x^3+x^2$

However $Q(1)=8$ and this implies that that $Q=P$ as above so we are done!

Edit later - as per the comment below from @subrosar, since $Q$ has coefficients $0,1$, the fact that $Q(2)=2012$ implies that $Q$ must be the polynomial above directly as the binary decomposition of $2012$ is unique; then $Q(1)=8$ shows that $Q=P$ so $P$ is unique too!

Comment: Once you get to the polynomial with coefficients $0$ and $1$ I think you could use the fact that $2012$ can be uniquely expressed in binary to get the coefficients.

Comment: @subrosar that's a perfectly good point and I added a comment to point that out too

Comment: @Conrad Can you elaborate on line $6$? What is $c_k=1,b_r=0 $? Can you tell me more about setting $P_1$?About the idea of how to set $P1$ ?

Comment: It's easier with an example - assume say $k=1, a_1=5$ say, so then we have the term $5x$ in $P$; now $5=2^2+1$ - then we replace $5x$ by $x^3+x$ so the value at $2$ remains same but the value at $1$ strictly decreases; in this case $r=2, b_1=2, b_2=0$ so $c_1=1$; but if instead we have $6x$ say, we replace that by $x^3+x^2 $ since $6=2^2+2$ so now $r=2, b_1=2,  b_2=1$ so $c_1=0$

Answer (score -1):

So once you get that
$$P(x)=(x-1)(x-2)R(x)+2004x-1996$$
$$P(x)=(x^2-3x+2)R(x)+2004x-1996$$
We know that the coefficients of $R(x)$ must be integers. Let's say $R(x)$ is an integral polynomial of degree $n\geq 2$ (I'll leave the other cases to you, as they are pretty much the same process and simpler) so that
$$R(x)=a_0x^0+a_1x^1+\ldots a_nx^n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$$
We have that
$$P(x)=(x^2-3x+2)R(x)+2004x-1996$$
$$P(x)=-1996+2004x+(x^2-3x+2)\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$$
$$P(x)=-1996+2004x+\sum_{k=2}^na_{k-2}x^k+\sum_{k=1}^n -3a_{k-1}x^k+\sum_{k=0}^n 2a_kx^k$$
$$P(x)=(-1996+2a_0)+(2004-3a_0+2a_1)x+\sum_{k=2}^n a_{k-2}x^k+\sum_{k=2}^n -3a_{k-1}x^k+\sum_{k=2}^n 2a_kx^k$$
$$P(x)=(-1996+2a_0)+(2004-3a_0+2a_1)x+\sum_{k=2}^n \left((a_{k-2}-3a_{k-1}+2a_k)x^k\right)$$
So $R(x)$ is defined by any sequence of length $n$, $a_n$, that satisfies
$$\begin{cases} a_0\geq 998\\2a_1-3a_0\geq -2004\\ 2a_k-3a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}\geq 0~\forall k\geq 4\end{cases}$$
It's easy to see that there are infinite polynomials from there. Some more explicit, and simple constructions could be initial conditions that satisfy the first two inequalities, and then there immediately exists a sequence that satisfies the equality case $\forall k\geq 4$ (as long as you watch out for any parity conflicts).

Of course, another easy reason to see the existence of infinite polynomials is that we can easily make a valid polynomial for $R(x)$ of degree $n+1$ from a valid polynomial for $R(x)$ of degree $n$.

Comment: note that $\deg P \le 10$ since $2^{11} >2012$ so the number of polynomials is finite (actually there is only one)

Comment: @Conrad Oh whoops. That was a massive oversight. Hopefully there is some use of the sequence stuff I proved, but I'm not sure